# Rcpp installation hangs on Module.cpp on lightweight box

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rcpp

**Edit:**

A solution is to install from binary.

Dirk commented below that binaries of Rcpp (and RcppEigen and more...) exist for Debian linux distros like Ubuntu, which is what I was running on my micro instance. In fact the r-project supports a bunch of packages, read more here: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/.

So if you're on, say, Ubuntu, you can install from binary like so: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp`

---

I'm trying to install `Rcpp` on a Google Compute micro instance (only .5G memory and a shared CPU). I've been able to install other packages that required compilation in R, but `Rcpp` keeps hanging when compiling `Module.cpp`. Maybe it takes longer than the few hours I've given it but that seems unlikely.

```
trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3762481 bytes (3.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
```

It just spins here for hours. Any advice? Does Rcpp have some difficulty on lightweight machines?

Comment: If you cannot install from source ... just install a binary build of Rcpp -- they exist for all relevant distros.

Comment: I wasn't aware there were binaries for Linux distros. Thanks!

Comment: When @DirkEddelbuettel says "Relevant" distributions, that means debian based distributions. Good luck on CentOS...

Comment: But Luke is almost surely on a .deb based-one as I recognise the default compiler options we have in our R package...   And I _think_ even RHEL/CentOS have Rcpp.

Comment: Yep, I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: So `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp` is your friend.  And read https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ and pay attention to the c2d4u repo.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the host of r-cran-* binaries. Super useful and was totally unaware of the work on this. Thanks again!

Honestly, feels like this isn't a duplicate and you should post this as an answer as the advice/solution is quite different.